# Monster attacking directly considered as "battled"?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So if monster attacked directly, is it considered "battle"? So if [Michion, the Timelord](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Michion,_the_Timelord) attacked LP directly, his effect of halving LP activates?

I'm asking this because of [Michion, the Timelord](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Michion,_the_Timelord)'s effect:

> Cannot be Special Summoned from the Deck. If you control no monsters,
>   you can Normal Summon this card without Tributing. Cannot be destroyed
>   by battle or card effects. You take no battle damage from attacks
>   involving this card. At the end of the Battle Phase, **if this card**
>   **battled: Halve your opponent’s LP**. Once per turn, during your Standby
>   Phase: Shuffle this card into the Deck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, the effect of Michion will activate; direct attacks are included in what are considered "battles".

From *Yu-Gi-Oh! TCG Official Rulebook ver9.1 p48*

> When a card requires a
>   monster to have “battled” (past tense), the attack had to have reached the
>   damage calculation portion of the Damage Step in order for the monster to
>   have “battled”. If the attack stops before damage calculation, the monster
>   did not “battle”.

So, provided Michion's attack reached damage calculation without being interrupted, the effect to halve the opponent's LP will activate at the end of the Battle Phase.